# What did Jesse Pinkman mumble in the flashback scene of Breaking Bad S05E14?

Tags: breaking-bad, dialogue

In *Breaking Bad* Season 5, Episode 14, there is a flashback scene at the start of the episode that shows Walt and Jesse during their first time cooking. When Jesse asks how much longer, Walt begins to explain that the reaction has begun and if they had a fridge it would work faster because the reaction is exothermic. When Walt turns around, Jesse says something under his breath. I watched this part over and over and cannot make out what he said. I looked for a script online, but found none. Does anyone know what Jesse said? At first I thought he was muttering to himself about how much money he will make by putting up with Walt. Then after listening again, I think it sounded more like he said something about a coma. But this doesn't make sense because Jesse doesn't know yet that Walt is sick.

Comment: When you want dialogue clarification, search for subtitles instead of a script. Those should be both easier to find and more accurate. Scripts show what a character was *supposed to say*, while subtitles show what they said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I remember correctly he says "Put me in a coma, why don't ya?" It has nothing to do with Walt being sick. This was a flashback to their very first cook together. As Jesse was a former student in Walt's chemistry class, they very much had a teacher/student relationship. Jesse had cooked before and thought he knew everything about the process. When Walt starting his "lecture" (the bit about it being a "exothermic reaction" etc) Jesse is bored and uninterested and his coma comment reflects that.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the intention to show he was bored. It just annoyed me I couldn't hear what he said.